# How to read more chunks in a .wav file in R?

Tags: r, audio, wav, chunks

I am reading a .wav file that has been collected using an hydrophone (underwater acoustics instrument). So far I have downloaded the two packages: tuneR and Seewave. 
I use readWave in tuneR:

```
> audio_file <-readWave("icListen_HF_test.wav")
> audio_file

Wave Object
    Number of Samples:      15360000
    Duration (seconds):     60
    Samplingrate (Hertz):   256000
    Channels (Mono/Stereo): Mono
    PCM (integer format):   TRUE
    Bit (8/16/24/32/64):    24
```

This is good, but for calculations purposes on the data, I need to access more information that's stored in this .wav file. 
According to the [OceanSonics manua](http://oceansonics.com/wp-content/uploads/icListen-Log-File-Formats4.pdf)l page 12 (see Table 3.3), there is a data chunk called **ICMT**, in which there are three values I need to get:

- Count At Full Scale Voltage,
- Full Scale Voltage, and
- Hydrophone Sensitivity.

How do I access those? I can't seem to find the function for it in those two packages I am using so far.

Thanks in advance for your help!